# Neighboring sums 4x4 game

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics, optimization

Here is an interesting game. You start with an empty 4x4 grid. At each turn you can choose an empty cell and place a value in it. The placed value is given by the following rules:

- If the chosen cell has no neighboring (horizontal or vertical) values then the placed value is 1.
- Otherwise the placed value is the sum of all neighboring (horizontal or vertical) values.

What is the largest value that you can achieve in this game?

Comment: Could you ask grid 5x5?

Comment: Done https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105340/neighboring-sums-5x5-game

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best solution my computer found is

> 41

I suspect this is optimal.

> ```
>   1  1  2  1
>   5  4  3  1
>   5  9 26 27
>   5 14 14 41
> ```

I won't list the order, as you can simply choose the squares according to the increasing order of the numbers.

Comment: "as you can simply choose the squares according to the increasing order of the numbers."

This doesn't seem to be true to me.  In particular, I suspect *which* 5 you place first matters a lot.

Comment: Well done! I have verified that this is the optimal answer. There is another solution that achieves the same score, but uses a slightly different path that does not involve number 27.

Comment: Is there a way to find the solution without using a computer?

Answer (score 10):

Here is my answer:

> 38

as here

> [image]

the order is as below

> [image]

Answer (score 6):

My first 3 tries, in the order of increasing score:

> Score **20**. Simply going row-wise, which produces a part of Pascal's triangle:
>
> ```
> 1  1  1  1
> 1  2  3  4
> 1  3  6  10
> 1  4  10 20
> ```

> Score **32**. An approach similar to the above, but placing ones at (1,3) and (3,1) first to boost the middle:
>
> ```
> 1  2  1  1
> 2  4  5  6
> 1  5  10 16
> 1  6  16 32
> ```

> Score **37**. An approach that utilizes Fibonacci sequence. Place the numbers in this order
>
> ```
> 1  3  4  5
> 16 2  6  7
> 15 14 10 8
> 13 12 11 9
> ```
>
> which gives this:
>
> ```
> 1  2  2  2
> 37 1  3  5
> 35 22 8  5
> 13 13 13 5
> ```

Comment: Love your work! This puzzle turned out more interesting than I realized :)

Comment: Damn, I just got the same result, then looked up to see that you'd just posted this :-(

Answer (score 1):

I found three solutions that all achieve the following score, with *more or less* the same chain but finishing in different positions:

> 41

corner:

> ```
>  41 27  1  1
>  14 26  3  2
>  14  9  4  1
>   5  5  5  1
> ```

edge:

> ```
>  14 41  1  1
>  14 26  3  2
>  14  9  4  1
>   5  5  5  1
> ```

interior:

> ```
>  14 15  1  1
>  14 41  3  2
>  14  9  4  1
>   5  5  5  1
> ```

A computer search determined that this score is optimal.

Comment: Nice work! I haven't seen the interior solution before.