# Neighboring sums 5x5 game

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics, optimization

You start with an empty 5x5 grid. At each turn you choose an empty cell and place a value in it. The placed value is given by the following rules:

- If the chosen cell has no neighboring (horizontal or vertical) values then the placed value is 1.
- Otherwise the placed value is the sum of all neighboring (horizontal or vertical) values.

What is the largest value that you can achieve in this game?

Here is the same puzzle for the 4x4 grid: [Neighboring sums 4x4 game](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105334/neighboring-sums-4x4-game)

Comment: Isn't this an [tag:open-ended] question?

Comment: @zixuan: there's provably an upper bound. I don't have quite enough math, but it's certainly lower than 67108864 = 2^26, which would require each new square to double the last square that was entered 25 times, which is clearly impossible (if for no other reason than there must be at least two "1" squares).

Comment: A helper for trying this puzzle: https://jsfiddle.net/9ebu8v02/

Comment: @tsh this is awesome, thank you! I wish I knew JavaScript - it would really help with making little visual prototypes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best solution my computer found is

> 448

I suspect this is optimal.

> ```
>   8   8   8   1   1
>  23  15   7   3   2
>  42  19   4   4   1
>  42  61 168 172 173
>  42 103 103 275 448
> ```

I won't list the order, as you can simply choose the squares according to the increasing order of the numbers.

The computer program I used started with choosing the 25 locations in any order. It then tried swapping the order of two randomly chosen locations around to see if that improved the score, and if so accept that swap. Repeat those swap attempts a large number of times, so that it has (probably) found a local maximum. It then does all this many times, keeping track of the best local maximum so far, hopefully eventually finding the global maximum.

**Edit:**
For fun I tried 6x6:

> Score: 8815
>
> ```
>   19   19   19    4    4    1
>   53   34   15    7    3    2
>   53   95    8    8    1    1
>  148   95  737  745 3895 8815
>  148  243  634 1379 3149 4919
>  148  391  391 1770 1770 1770
> ```

and 7x7:

> Score: 214548
>
> ```
>  42   42   42    8     8      1      1
> 118   76   34   15     7      3      2
> 118  213   19   19     4      4      1
> 331  213 2857 2876 24751  24755  24756
> 331  544 2625 5501 21871  46626  71382
> 331  875 2081 7582 16370 134378  71382
> 331 1206 1206 8788  8788 143166 214548
> ```

and 8x8:

> Score: 8203779
>
> ```
>      1      1      8       8      42      42     213     213
>      2      3      7      15      34      76     171     384
>      1      4      4      19      19      95      95     479
>  36313  36312  36308    7314    7295    1627    1532     479
> 101615  65302  28990   12963    5649    2585     958     479
> 182944  81329  16027   16027    3064    3064     479     479
> 182944 264273 727517  743544 1937369 1940433 5072106 5072585
> 182944 447217 447217 1190761 1190761 3131194 3131194 8203779
> ```

Edit: Dmitry Kamenetsky got a better 8x8:

> Score: 9008465
>
> ```
>      95      95      95      19      19      4      4      1
>     266     171      76      34      15      7      3      2
>     266     479      42      42       8      8      1      1
>     745     479    3714    3756   19631  19639  99570  99571
>     745    1224    3193    6949   15867  35506  79930 179501
>     745    1969    1969    8918    8918  44424  44424 223925
> 5571135 5570390 2131091 2129122  813965 805047 268349 223925
> 9008465 3437330 3437330 1306239 1306239 492274 492274 223925
> ```

These larger squares are less likely to be optimal.

Comment: What does your computer give for grid 100x100?

Comment: @TigerTV.ru That would easily overflow the long integer type, so it would take a bit of work to adapt my program. It would also highly likely not get anywhere even close to optimal in a reasonable time since the number of possibilities are so astronomically huge.

Comment: I haven't found the sequence [here](https://oeis.org/).

Comment: Well done you got it! I wrote a program that is very similar to yours (swapping pairs of locations). I cannot achieve a better score, so I suspect this is optimal. There are some other solutions but they all get the same score. There is one solution that doesn't use 275.

Comment: I was able to match your solution for 6x6. So I suspect that one is optimal too.

Comment: For your interest my best solution for 7x7 is 214548. I could only reach it once, so it is probably not optimal. It is an interesting solution, because the largest number does not lie on the edge.

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky I get the same answer for 7x7, but picked a solution with the largest number in a corner.

Comment: This is great! Do you get 6 for grid 3x3?

Comment: @TigerTV.ru On 3x3 you can reach 10: (1,2,1)(2,4,5)(1,5,10). Interesting that my solutions for 5x5-7x7 all fill in a 3x3 corner first, but don't reach 10.

Comment: good to know that you get the same for 7x7. Could be optimal. I think I will make an integer sequence out of this.

Comment: The 331 repeats 4 times in 7x7. Maybe there is a way to repeat it less.

Comment: The best progress is made if high numbers are combined as much as possible. So zigzagging on some band will give the best asymptotic exponential growth.
I thought that a band of width two would be optimal, with the golden ratio's gain of 61.8% per 2 cells. However each turn has a cost. 
It turns out that the asymptotic gains (rounded) per cell are 27.2%, 31.0%, 30.3% and 28.6% for width 2,3,4,and 5 bands respectively.
It remains to get the best start, and to minimize the cost of turning, but e.g. on a 100*100 square, using 32 bands of 3 and 1 band of 4 might be close to optimal.

Comment: For 8x8 I managed to get 9008465: https://pastebin.com/K9mznEzB

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky, Oh, you've changed repeating of 479 by 5 times, and now maximum length is 3. The max number is in a corner.

Answer (score 4):

The highest I have gotten without the aid of a computer is:

> 397

Solution:

> `1 ,2  ,1   ,177 ,397`
>  `3 ,2  ,101 ,176 ,220`
>  `3 ,5  ,98  ,75  ,44`
>  `8 ,5  ,18  ,31  ,44`
>  `8 ,13 ,13  ,13  ,13`
>
>  Order of input:
>  
>  `1  ,3  ,2  ,23 ,25`
>  `5  ,4  ,21 ,21 ,24`
>  `6  ,7  ,20 ,19 ,18`
>  `9  ,8  ,13 ,15 ,17`
>  `10 ,11 ,12 ,14 ,16`

Strategy:

> Have to start with a `1,2,1` combination of some sort just to get the ball rolling. I figured it's best to get one of the `1`s in a corner, out of the way. Then snaking down the left side allowed me to keep the `5` next to the centre square. As I then snaked across the bottom I realised the mistake in my first attempt was to not keep the `31` near the middle. So I changed this and continued to work around the edge. This time instead of going all the way up the right side, I moved into the middle. This allowed for a greater number to finish in the top-right.

---

First Attempt:

> 209

> `1 , 2  , 1   , 166 , 49`
>  `3 , 2  , 119 , 116 , 49`
>  `3 , 5  , 209 , 67  , 49`
>  `8 , 5  , 18  , 18  , 49`
>  `8 , 13 , 13  , 31  , 31`
>
>  Order of input:
>  
>  `1  ,3  ,2  ,23 ,22`
>  `5  ,4  ,24 ,21 ,20`
>  `6  ,7  ,25 ,19 ,18`
>  `9  ,8  ,13 ,14 ,17`
>  `10 ,11 ,12 ,15 ,16`
>  
>  My strategy here was to try and work towards finishing on the centre cell, so I tried to keep the larger numbers towards the middle.

Comment: how!! my code got me 189 :think:

Comment: @OmegaKrypton: I just tried to keep the high numbers near the middle. I have a new answer now... solution to follow...

Comment: ah my code is still burning ig, may yield something higher than that, hopefully. anyways, gj!

Answer (score 1):

Note: My suggestion below is disproved.

Not an answer, but regarding being open ended: I do expect that the following generalization holds as optimal solution for any odd square grid. And that might be provable optimal. (even though I do not see how to do that)

> [image]

Comment: This is not optimal for $n=3$.  What does it yield for $n=7$?

Comment: I stand corrected ; only 142069 (if I calculated correctly)

Answer (score 0):

So... no [no-computer](/questions/tagged/no-computer) so...

These are the solutions that yield highest of 189. For each pair of lines, the first line are the 25 numbers. The second line is the order in which they are filled.

> 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 3 4 5 1 3 6 10 15 75 74 71 25 15 75 189 40 40 15
> ---0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 19 18 24 23 22 17 16 15 20 21
> 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 3 4 5 1 3 6 10 15 75 74 71 25 15 189 114 40 40 15
> ---0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 19 18 24 23 22 17 16 15 21 20
> 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 3 4 5 1 3 6 10 15 75 74 71 25 15 189 114 40 40 15
> ---0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 19 18 24 23 22 17 16 21 15 20
> 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 3 4 5 1 3 6 10 15 189 74 71 25 15 114 114 40 40 15
> ---0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 19 18 24 23 22 17 16 21 20 15
> 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 3 4 5 1 3 6 10 15 75 74 71 25 15 75 189 40 40 15
> ---0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 19 24 18 23 22 17 16 15 20 21
> 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 3 4 5 1 3 6 10 15 75 74 71 25 15 189 114 40 40 15
> ---0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 19 24 18 23 22 17 16 15 21 20
> 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 3 4 5 1 3 6 10 15 75 74 71 25 15 189 114 40 40 15
> ---0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 19 24 18 23 22 17 16 21 15 20
> 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 3 4 5 1 3 6 10 15 189 74 71 25 15 114 114 40 40 15
> ---0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 19 24 18 23 22 17 16 21 20 15

Anyways, i guess my compiler is too (insert poop) to take 25! permutations. So here is my C++ code. If anyone manages to reach higher with this code please kindly comment!

````
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std;
int order[25];
int grid[25];
int max_val = 189;
//order[0] means the first processed grid
bool nw = false;
int find_val(int place){
    int sum = 0;
    if (place > 4){
        sum += grid[place-5];
    }
    if (place < 20){
        sum += grid[place+5];
    }
    if (place % 5 != 0){
        sum += grid[place-1];
    }
    if (place % 5 != 4){
        sum += grid[place+1];
    }
    if (sum == 0){
        sum = 1;
    }
    if (sum >= max_val){
        max_val = sum;
        nw = true;
    }
    return sum;
}

void fill(){
    for(int i=0;i<25;i++){
        grid[order[i]] = find_val(order[i]);
    }
}

int main(){
    int input;
    cin>>input;
    cout<<"im here"<<endl;
    for (int i=0;i<25;i++){
        order[i]=i;
        grid[i]=0;
    }
    cout<<"init done"<<endl;
    do{
        nw = false;
        for (int i=0;i<25;i++){
            grid[i]=0;
        }
        fill(); 
        for (int i=0;i<25 & nw;i++){
            cout<<grid[i]<<' ';
        }
        if (nw) cout<<endl;
        if (nw) cout<<"---";
        for (int i=0;i<25 & nw;i++){
            cout<<order[i]<<' ';
        }
        if (nw) cout<<endl;
    } while (next_permutation(order, order + 25)); 
    return 0;
}

```
````

Comment: 25! is a large number...

Comment: Just 25!=15511210043330985984000000

Comment: It's not "just"... As nowadays computer may take 1,000,000,000 operations in one second, maybe you want to wait for 3,000,000,000 years to finish this...

Comment: @athin, Often maths helps when computer can't.